# PHP if statement to echo info from form

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a form review page that works great calling:

```
echo "<div class='reviewItem'><span class='reviewTitle'>Cusomer Name:</span>{$_REQUEST['CustomerName']}</div>";
echo "<div class='reviewItem'><span class='reviewTitle'>Cusomer Email:</span>{$_REQUEST['CustomerEmail']}</div>";
echo "<div class='reviewItem'><span class='reviewTitle'>Customer Phone:</span>{$_REQUEST['CustomerPhone']}</div>";
echo "<div class='reviewItem'><span class='reviewTitle'>Customer Address:</span>{$_REQUEST['CustomerAddress']}</div>";
```

The problem is that I have a ton of fields that don't get filled out. I want to put an "if" statement before the echo to check if it has data. if not, nothing gets displayed. I am very new to PHP, so I'm not sure if I can call something like:

```
if (length > 0)echo "<div class='reviewItem'><span class='reviewTitle'>Cusomer Email:</span>{$_REQUEST['CustomerEmail']}</div>";
```

Thanks in advance for any help. Cheers.

Comment: echo (condition) ? "<div ...></div>" : false;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo (!empty($_REQUEST['CustomerName'])) ? "<div class='reviewItem'><span class='reviewTitle'>Cusomer Name:</span>  {$_REQUEST['CustomerName']}</div>" : "";
echo (!empty($_REQUEST['CustomerEmail'])) ? "<div class='reviewItem'><span class='reviewTitle'>Cusomer Email:</span>{$_REQUEST['CustomerEmail']}</div>" : "";
echo (!empty($_REQUEST['CustomerPhone'])) ? "<div class='reviewItem'><span class='reviewTitle'>Customer Phone:</span>{$_REQUEST['CustomerPhone']}</div>" :"";
echo (!empty($_REQUEST['CustomerAddress'])) ? "<div class='reviewItem'><span class='reviewTitle'>Customer Address:</span>{$_REQUEST['CustomerAddress']}</div>" : "";
```

Try that.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['CustomerName']))
    echo "<div class='reviewItem'><span class='reviewTitle'>Cusomer Name:</span>{$_REQUEST['CustomerName']}</div>";
```

or

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['CustomerName']) && $_REQUEST['CustomerName'])
    echo "<div class='reviewItem'><span class='reviewTitle'>Cusomer Name:</span>{$_REQUEST['CustomerName']}</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You've just about got it.  Try this:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['CustomerName']}))
     echo "<div class='reviewItem'><span class='reviewTitle'>Cusomer Name:</span>{$_REQUEST['CustomerName']}</div>";
```

PHP's [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) checks to see if the referenced variable has a value assigned - if it does, echo it.

Answer (score 0):

I usually write it like this, which tests for the var being set and not blank:

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['CustomerName']) && $_REQUEST['CustomerName']!=''){
 echo "<div class='reviewItem'><span class='reviewTitle'>Customer Name:</span>{$_REQUEST['CustomerName']}</div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: You don't need to check two conditions if you want to prevent empty strings:  `if(!empty($_REQUEST['CustomerName')){...}`

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
if($_REQUEST['CustomerName']):
    echo "<div class='reviewItem'><span class='reviewTitle'>Cusomer Name:</span>{$_REQUEST['CustomerName']}</div>";
endif;
if($_REQUEST['CustomerEmail']):
    echo "<div class='reviewItem'><span class='reviewTitle'>Cusomer Email:</span>{$_REQUEST['CustomerEmail']}</div>";
endif;
if($_REQUEST['CustomerPhone']):
    echo "<div class='reviewItem'><span class='reviewTitle'>Customer Phone:</span>{$_REQUEST['CustomerPhone']}</div>";
endif;
if($_REQUEST['CustomerAddress']): 
    echo "<div class='reviewItem'><span class='reviewTitle'>Customer Address:</span>{$_REQUEST['CustomerAddress']}</div>";
endif;
```

Comment: I don't understand why people still use `if: endif;`, especially in a case like this.  It's just noise

Comment: its easier to read if you have other stuff like html etc.. you would want to know what that stray `}` mean, right? unless you want to trace it back above..

Comment: @reikyoushin: proper code formating and avoiding of mixing php+html make miracles

Comment: i know MVC is a good approach but there are situations when you need to add stuff together..

Comment: @Mr. Alien - `You call } => stray?` if the code is too long, especially on nested curly braces, you could confuse it with something else like a closing character on `for(){`, `try{`, etc.. if you get what i mean..

Comment: well, im using eclipse PDT. but we can go on like forever debating here but for me its more readable that way..

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the short way:

```
echo (isset($_REQUEST['CustomerName'])) ? "<div class='reviewItem'><span class='reviewTitle'>Cusomer Name:</span>{$_REQUEST['CustomerName']}</div>" : false;
```

Logic:

```
echo (condition) ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

Comment: Will it work?  Yes.  But something about `echo false` rubs me the wrong way.  And how is this "the short way"? It's more characters than using a simple if statement.